# How may one go about finding a definite reference to one or more examples of specific criminal cases that were prosecuted by or on behalf of TfL?

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales, legal-research, public-transport

According to TfL’s official prosecutions policy, it seems as though they may do some of the prosecutions themselves. How could one go about finding examples of such cases that have been prosecuted in such a manner in the past? And what terminology would this fall under if it has happened? Would it be considered a “private prosecution,” even though undertaken by a specifically public body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Mayor of London's Revenue Enforcement & Prosecutions Policy](https://content.tfl.gov.uk/revenue-enforcement-and-prosecutions-policy.pdf) says that TfL Approved Prosecutors prosecute 'fare evasion':

- on TFL Rail & London Underground, contrary to the provisions of the [Regulation of Railways Act 1889](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Vict/52-53/57) and the [TfL Railway Byelaws](https://tfl.gov.uk/corporate/terms-and-conditions/byelaws), and
- on  London Buses, contrary to [section 67 of the Public Passenger Vehicles Act 1981](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1981/14/section/67).

Being summary only offences, dealt with by letter (Single Justice Procedure Notices and Postal Requisitions) and magistrates' court, it's unlikely there will be many (if any) case summaries or judgments freely available online. There are some purportedly real scans of letters online.

Some statistics are available, published in response to Freedom of Information Act requests. See for example Request IDs [FOI-0278-2324](https://tfl.gov.uk/corporate/transparency/freedom-of-information/foi-request-detail?referenceId=FOI-0278-2324) and [FOI-2301-2223](https://tfl.gov.uk/corporate/transparency/freedom-of-information/foi-request-detail?referenceId=FOI-2301-2223).

Some solicitors' websites may publish case studies that the solicitors use to promote hiring them to help defend against or settle such prosecutions.

The web forum [Railforums.co.uk has a section for Disputes and Prosecutions](https://www.railforums.co.uk/forums/disputes-prosecutions.152/), which comprises people asking what they should do in some circumstances and other people advising them what to do and/or what to expect.

More serious offences such as sexual offences, violence, criminal damage and behaviour that amounts to serious fraud is reported to the police and prosecuted by the Crown Prosecution Service.